# sql agent job: How to set max run time for powershell step

Tags: sql-server

sql server 2014

We hvae a powershell step that does a robocopy operation that sometimes hangs for unknown reasons.

Can we set a max run time, either at the robocopy command level, or at the job step level?

(windows OS task scheduler has something like this...)

Comment: Sql agent nor Robocopy has such flexiblity. What you can do is have another job monitor your problematic job and when the max time reaches, have it stop the job using `sp_stop_job`. What you are doing is [not a good practice](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/516456/add-an-option-to-set-time-limits-for-sql-agent-jobs) as if the job is just about to complete and you set another job to stop that job just before completion then it has to ROLLBACK all the work that it did.

Comment: @Kin Thanks! OK... not a good practice... so what is the right practice to automatically manage a hung job?